# Can bootstrapping improve the test power, when the sample size is small?

Tags: bootstrap, sample-size, statistical-power

1. When the sample is small and study is under-powered, can bootstrapping be used to *generate* data and increase the sample size (and improve the test power)?
2. Is there any way that bootstrapping can be used to improve the power, *without* generating data?
3. When bootstrapping is used to generate data (if possible), must the level of significance be reduced to compensate for the inflated power due to the **fake** newly generated data?
4. Can you cite any references about "bootstrapping to improve power, and its rules"?

This is a general question. My concern is not just to increase the power (by *any* methods including using a better test or increasing the sample size), but **increase the power via bootstrapping**. I just want to know (by some references) whether bootstrapping can be a remedy for small, under-powered samples? And if so, how?

Comment: You can always improve the power without generating data: use a decision rule that invariably rejects the null hypothesis.  The problem with your question is that the power depends on the statistical test as well as the model of the data, and both of those will determine to what extent the power might be improved by selecting some alternative procedure (whether bootstrapping or something else).   Could you therefore edit this question to make it a little less general and more focused on the problem you actually face?

Comment: Thanks dear whuber. My concern was not to increase the power of *my* study, but to check, as a general question, to see if bootstrapping can be used in any way to increase the power. Lets say there is a study design where the best test is being used for analyzing a particular model. Yet the test is still under-powered, because the study is a pilot one, it is not possible to add more datapoints. Now, can bootstrapping be used to increase the power?

Comment: By definition and assumption, that is not possible: when you apply the *best* test--in the sense of being most powerful for its size--it's not possible to do better.

Comment: That seems what I wanted. Whuber I see my question is suspended. Please note that it *is* a specific question (with 2 branches). It is not about a single study. It is a good question never asked before on the internet (to my knowledge), so let it live please.

Comment: Or at least let me edit it and narrow it down. It is closed and uneditable!

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, Vic: since you are the originator, you have the ability to edit the post.  I am reluctant unilaterally to override the votes of five other users: the fact that they voted to close this question means there is a genuine need to clarify it.

Comment: Thanks whuber. Sure I would do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That may be possible in some cases, although you should not expect miracles.

The main reason to use a bootstrap for testing purposes (which is how I read your reference to "power") is usually to find an approximation to the *null* distribution of test statistics.

Here is a simple example. I generate data `x` from (of course, that is something which is unknown in practice!) a N(3,1), where it is assumed (just for simplicity) that we know the variance is one.

`x.star` generates, by sampling with replacement from `x`, resamples, `B` times in total. I.e., we then sample from a sample with mean `xbar`. In order to get bootstrap test statistics that behave like standard normals - i.e., the behavior of the test statistic when the null is true - we therefore need to subtract the "bootstrap population mean" `xbar` from each of the sample averages of the bootstrap samples `mean(x.star)`. This is analogous to subtracting the mean under null, $\mu_0$ from $\bar x$ in the numerator of a standard non-bootstrap test statistic.

When you do that many, `B`, times, we can use these bootstrap test statistics to build a bootstrap distribution that may serve as a null distribution against which to compare the realized test statistic:

```
library(boot)
n <- 5000
x <- rnorm(n, 3)     # data
xbar <- mean(x)      # mean
B <- 1e5             # number of bootstrap resamples
t.star <- rep(NA,B)

for (b in 1:B){
  x.star <- sample(x, n, replace=T)             # bootstrap data
  t.star[b] <- sqrt(n)*(mean(x.star)-xbar)      # bootstrap test statistic - by subtracting xbar, we make it behave like a N(0,1)
}

t <- abs(sqrt(n)*xbar)                          # test statistic for testing mu=0

bs.cv <- quantile(abs(t.star), .95)             # bootstrap critical value. reject if abs(t) > bs.cv
bs.cv
qnorm(.975)                                     # asymptotic c.v. For n,B large, bs.cv \approx bs.cv

> bs.cv
     95% 
1.936338 
> qnorm(.975)
[1] 1.959964
```

Of course, in practice we would rather use such approaches where the usual asymptotic approximation may be untractable, e.g., due to nuisance parameters whose effect cannot (easily) be accounted for.

That said, there is much literature on bootstrap tests providing asymptotic refinements (e.g., [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=quL_WHqbpNMC&pg=PA3191&lpg=PA3191&dq=bootstrap+refinements&source=bl&ots=edNO3rBcsW&sig=ACfU3U1u6K7hQaPzuWTze1bkRv_EdPikIg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjl6cbl95LhAhVFJFAKHZM8CS44ChDoATADegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=bootstrap%20refinements&f=false)), i.e., faster convergence of the rejection rates to the nominal level. If the error-in-rejection probability of the underlying test using standard asymptotic critical values was such that it underrejected, a refinement will more completely exhaust the nominal rejection probability, and therefore, typically, also higher power, as a test that rejects more frequently when the null is true typically also does so when it is not.

Comment: I believe the bootstrap is not usually justified as you claim.  The point is that the data you *have* are supposed to reflect the population.  If the null does not hold, then doesn't it clearly follow that sampling from the data will *not* sample from the null?

Comment: @whuber, of course, when you resample from the sample directly (and I certainly did not write that this is all one should do!), that will not approximate the null distribution, which is why bootstrapping the null distribution of hypothesis tests involves a step where you ensure that the behaviour of the bootstrap test statistics mimics that of the test statistic *when the null is true*. The actual test statistic, in turn, of course won't be from that distribution and hence be larger, which is where the bootstrap test gets its power from.

Comment: Please refer to the above illustration/edit and, e.g., [Horowitz, Handbook of econometrics, Ch. 52](https://www.sciencedirect.com/handbook/handbook-of-econometrics/vol/5/suppl/C), Sec. 3.3 for more discussion.
So, I stand by my answer.

Comment: "When you resample from the sample directly" is practically the *definition* of the bootstrap.  Perhaps you have in mind some kind of parametric bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, that is kind of the definition of the bootstrap. The rest of my answer tries to indicate how to use that bootstrap sample for the purposes of hypothesis testing via building a null distribution that may serve as a (possibly superior) alternative to the more conventional asymptotic null distribution. My point is unrelated to parametric vs. nonparametric bootstraps.

Comment: It takes a close study of your code in order to infer that's your point.  Please consider elaborating on it in the English portion of your answer.

Comment: @whuber, I have tried to explain my code/idea in more detail.

Answer (score 9):

I like Christoph's answer (+1) but I think your question reflects some basic misunderstanding of what bootstrap is and how it works. It's true that bootstrapping  generates data, but this data is used to get a better idea of the sampling distribution of some statistic, not to increase power Christoph points out a way that this may increase power anyway, but it's not by increasing the sample size.

If you could do that, then everyone would use very small samples and just bootstrap bigger ones. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: Thanks dear Peter. This is exactly what I wanted to hear; this is why I called the newly generated data [if added to the original sample] as a fake one; yet I have colleagues who do that! But do you have a text-book sort of reference for it?

Comment: I don't know of a textbook that explicitly says this, but any book on bootstrapping implies it. The generated data is in a separate universe.

Comment: Hi Peter. Sorry for bothering you here as apparently there was no way to direct-message you on CV. Can you give an answer to my problem? It is clearly stated in the first section of this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/636596/multilevel-mixed-linear-regression-with-pseudo-repeats-why-designate-repeated