# Determining the power associated with the logistic model

Tags: r, logistic, statistical-power

Although there has been some detailed discussions about power analysis on this website (for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22406/power-analysis-for-ordinal-logistic-regression/22410#22410) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234696/how-do-you-conduct-a-power-analysis-for-logistic-regression-in-r)), the answer provided to this question has  outlines the steps to simulating a power analysis, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35940/simulation-of-logistic-regression-power-analysis-designed-experiments).

Say we take some data (data was linked to a [bootstrapping question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59829/which-bootstrapped-regression-model-should-i-choose))

We create a regression that will predict `admit` based on the two continous variables `gpa` and `gre`

- Now we have a `n=400`.
- We can then elect our power level, `alpha = 0.5`
- The effect size you would like to detect, e.g., odds ratios  (we obtain this from our regression)

So in following the detailed method provided by @gung [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35940/simulation-of-logistic-regression-power-analysis-designed-experiments), I want to run the simulation. Here is the code I have adjusted, but my output is not correct. Can someone outline what I have not understood

```
mydata <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
head(mydata)

set.seed(1234)

my.mod <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa , data = mydata, family = "binomial")


repetitions <- length(mydata$admit)

gre <- mydata$gre
gpa <- mydata$gpa


significant = matrix(nrow=repetitions, ncol=4)

for(i in 1:repetitions){
  responses          = mydata$admit
  #responses          = rbinom(n=N, size=1, prob=mydata$admit)      # we can interchange this comment
  model              = glm(responses ~ gre + gpa, family = binomial(link="logit"))
  significant[i,1:2] = (summary(model)$coefficients[2:3,4]<.05)
  significant[i,3]   = sum(significant[i,1:2])
  modelDev           = model$null.deviance-model$deviance
  significant[i,4]   = (1-pchisq(modelDev, 2))<.05
}



sum(significant[,1])/repetitions      # pre-specified effect power for gre

sum(significant[,2])/repetitions      # pre-specified effect power for gpa

sum(significant[,4])/repetitions  # power for likelihood ratio test of model

sum(significant[,3]==2)/repetitions   # all effects power

sum(significant[,3]>0)/repetitions    # any effect power
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't actually simulated anything; you've just done the same thing multiple times to the same data. Even if you use `responses = rbinom(n=N, size=1, prob=mydata$admit)`, that's not correct because `admit` is the dependent variable (taking values of 0 or 1) rather than being probabilities.