# Is one-way ANOVA robust to violations of homoscedasticity?

Tags: anova, heteroscedasticity, normality-assumption

I read [here](https://pythonfordatascience.org/anova-python/#assumptions) that if group sizes are equal, ANOVA is robust against the violation of the assumptions of normality and homoscedasticity.

I am wondering if this is the case, and if so why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Welch one-way ANOVA.** Maybe so, but I think it is better to use a Welch version of the one-way ANOVA---as shown briefly below in R. This test is similar to the Welch two-sample t test, *specifically designed* to accommodate unequal variances.

```
x1 = rnorm(10, 50, 2);   x2 = rnorm(10, 50, 4)
x3 = rnorm(10, 55, 4);   x4 = rnorm(10, 60, 5)
x = c(x1, x2, x3, x4);  gp = rep(1:4, each=10)
```

These data are simulated to have among-group differences in both means and variances.

```
boxplot(x ~ gp, col="skyblue2", pch=20)
```

[image]

```
oneway.test(x ~ gp)

        One-way analysis of means 
     (not assuming equal variances)

data:  x and gp
F = 28.896, num df = 3.000, denom df = 18.466, 
   p-value = 3.463e-07
```

*Note:* In a standard on-way ANOVA one would have a `denom df`
of $4(10 - 1) = 36$ degrees of freedom.

**References:** This [web page](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/bwebb/statistics/ANOVA_in_R.pdf) discussed ad-hoc tests and other relevant details. This excellent [Answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91872/alternatives-to-one-way-anova-for-heteroskedastic-data) by @gung on our own site explores this test and other related issues. Perhaps explore other "Related" links
provided in the right-hand margin of this page.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this alternative!