# Dealing with Heteroskedasticity: when to use WLS vs Box-Cox/Box Tidwel Transformation

Tags: data-transformation, heteroscedasticity, wls

Suppose you are fitting a linear model which has heteroskedastic (non-constant) residuals. I have read that there are a number of ways of dealing with this situation, including Weighted Least Squares (WLS) estimation and applying Box-Cox and/or Box Tidwel transformation.

As far as I understand, the WLS computes weights and assigns them to each observation as to make spread of residuals more constant. For example, data points with large residuals receive lower weights.

The Box-Cox transformation is essentially a power transformation to the DV: the y variable. The Box-Tidwel transforms the IVs: X variables to make their relation with Y linear.

What I am interested in is in which cases would you prefer WLS over transformations and vice versa? Or is it simply a trial-and-error process of trying different methods? Some intuitive and experience-based explanations would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hopefully you'll get a much better answer than I can give you.  I think current thinking is to not use transformations, but to either use an appropriate generalized linear model or to use a method like WLS.  You might also look into methods that adjust for heteroscedasticity.  For one-way designs there's Welch's anova.  And R offers white-ajusted anova for heteroscedasticity.  There's lots of discussion here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/91881/166526

Comment: @SalMangiafico thank you for your reply! I greatly appreciate it!