# What is the dispersion parameter of binomial distribution?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, exponential-family, dispersion

Binomial distribution is a member of exponential dispersion models, but I can not find the dispersion parameter of it.

Could anyone help me find it out?

IMO the Binomial distribution only has an ordinary parameter p which describes both the mean and variance of this distribution, and I think there can't be the second parameter, neither does the dispersion parameter!

I find an answer in page 213 of [Generalized Linear Models With Examples in R](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-0118-7). But it changes the form of binomial distribution.

Answer (score 4):

Using the definition of an exponential dispersion family at [Definition of exponential family with dispersion parameter](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413825/definition-of-exponential-family-with-dispersion-parameter?rq=1), we find that for the binomial family it is $a(\phi)=1$. Copying that definition here:
$$
   f(y|θ,ϕ)=exp\left(yθ−b(θ)a(ϕ)+c(y,ϕ)\right)
$$

For the binomial distribution with mean $np=\mu$, say, the variance is $\sigma^2=np(1-p)=\mu(1-\mu/n)$, so is a function of the mean (assuming $n$ a fixed constant). Still, sometimes it is estimated as if a free parameter (if the binomial is seen as a model just for the mean, not for the dispersion, called under/over-dispersion). That must be done in the framework of quasi-likelihood, see [Mean-variance relationship in the quasi-likelihood](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/535156/mean-variance-relationship-in-the-quasi-likelihood), [What is the difference between logistic regression and Fractional response regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216122/what-is-the-difference-between-logistic-regression-and-fractional-response-regre)

Giving more details, showing how the binomial probability mass function can be written in the above form:
\begin{align}
f(y \mid p) &= \binom{n}{y} p^y (1-p)^{n-y} \\
 &= \exp\left\{ \log\binom{n}{y} + y\log(p/(1-p)) - n\log(1-p)  \right\} \quad\text{Now writing $\theta=\log(p/(1-p))$} \\
 &= \exp\left\{ y\theta - n\log(1-p) + \log\binom{n}{y}  \right\} \\
&= \exp\left\{ \frac{y\theta + n\log(1+e^\theta)}{1} + \log\binom{n}{y}  \right\}
\end{align} making it clear that we have to choose $a(\phi)=1$ to match that particular definition.  In this case we could clearly simplify the definition, by replacing $a(\phi)$ by $\phi$, which is what is done in forinstance the R implementation `glm` for logistic regression.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! So can I think that the binomial distribution does not contain the dispersion parameter？I am pretty confused because I think the core of exponential dispersion models is the dispersion parameter!

Comment: Also, I wonder if the definition of  exponential dispersion family in your link is equal to that in Wikipedia?

Comment: @vegetabletina It's also $1$ for the Poisson distribution. And the exponential distribution.

Comment: @Glen_b    Is a(Φ) or Φ equal to 1?

Comment: @vegetabletina For the binomial case (without observation-weights), the variance function is $\phi V(\mu)$ with $\phi=1$ and $V(\mu) = \mu(1-\mu)$. Just to be sure we're on the same page, what is the definition of $a(\phi)$ you're looking at?

Comment: @Glen_b I saw that from kjetil's link: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413825/definition-of-exponential-family-with-dispersion-parameter?rq=1