# How to model a data with heteroskedasticity in variance and outliers in R?

Tags: r, regression, heteroscedasticity, robust, lm

I have a dataset where variance is different across groups, and there exist some outliers too. I used robust linear regression `lmrob()` to handle outliers. However, I need a method that takes care of variance heteroscedasticity too.

Also, the application of such method in R can be very helpful.

Thanks in advance for your help. :)

Comment: Dealing with heteroscedasticity is a broad topic and there is no single black box function in R that solves it. So, could you explain more about the data. For instance, what sort of heteroscedasticity do you have? I am asking because possibly you can delay with it by using a data transformation.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I'm trying to explain a numerical target variable using two categorical variables. The target variable is zero-inflated in one group of explanatory variables, and has some outliers too. I could control for the outliers using robust regression, but the diagnostic plots show heterogeneity in variances. I hope that could clarify my question.

Comment: You have the distributions in each combination of categorical variables, right, like `black/dog`, `white/dot`, `black/cat`, and `white/cat`? What more do you hope to get from running a regression?

Comment: You might see this post for some options for handling heteroscedasticity.   There's an example there of using `lmrob()` with weighted observations.  [stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91872/alternatives-to-one-way-anova-for-heteroskedastic-data/91881#91881](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91872/alternatives-to-one-way-anova-for-heteroskedastic-data/91881#91881)